# LWC and addEventListener

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am building a LWC with the intent to listen to an event from window.postMessage via window.addEventListner. However, after deploying the below code, I am not seeing any console logs from my LWC when I use chrome console to post the message to the window. I have tried using both `this.addEventListener` and `window.addEventListener`.

This is my first time building a LWC so I presume I am doing something wrong.

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';

export default class MyEventHandler extends LightningElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.addEventListener('message', this.handleMessage);
      }
      handleMessage = (event) => {
          console.log('event received')
          console.log(event);
      };
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You definitely need to use `window.addEventListener` and `window.removeEventListener`. I also recommend using connectedCallback instead of constructor (though it should work either way).

```
import { LightningElement } from "lwc";

export default class App extends LightningElement {
  message = 'none received (yet)'
  connectedCallback() {
    window.addEventListener('message', this.receiveMessage);
  }
  disconnectedCallback() {
    window.removeEventListener('message', this.receiveMessage);
  }
  receiveMessage = (event) => {
    this.message = event.data
  }
}
```

---

```
import { LightningElement, api } from "lwc";

export default class Child extends LightningElement {
  sendMessage() {
    window.postMessage('hello world', '*');
  }
}
```

Note that [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) keep their `this` reference to the class. If you use a normal function, you instead must use [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

```
  #receiveMessageCallback;
  connectedCallback() {
    this.#receiveMessageCallback = this.receiveMessage.bind(this);
    window.addEventListener('message', this.#receiveMessageCallback);
  }
  disconnectedCallback() {
    window.removeEventListener('message', this.#receiveMessageCallback);
  }
```

We need to store the original event handler (`#receiveMessageCallback`), otherwise we will leak memory when the component unloads.

[Demo](https://webcomponents.dev/edit/d7MtS3vlsLd6GqVL1CIr/src/child.js).

Comment: Thanks! That worked!

Comment: Are you sure this is correct? AFAIK you lose the "this" binding for the component when adding the event listener this way (against `window` rather than `this` or `this.template`).

Comment: @PhilW I should have explained better, I suppose. Unlike normal `function` objects, Arrow functions (`() => {}`) keep their `this` to whatever scope they are defined in. `receiveMessage(event)` wouldn't work here, but `receiveMessage = (event) => {...}` does.

Comment: A-ha, yes, I should have read the whole piece of code and spotted the arrow function for `this.receiveMessage`. My fault for not being thorough, but it's a good idea to add a bit of detail in the answer too :D

Comment: @PhilW Indeed. I've added more info to it. Thanks for calling that out.

Comment: Explains the two approaches nicely now. Upvoted. Is there a specific reason you used the hash on the start of the identifier, btw?

Comment: @PhilW It's the new [private class fields](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields). This makes it explicit that the property is not to be accessed outside the class.

Comment: Nice! Thanks for the link. Always learning...