# Custome Event Handling Function is no triggering by using addEventListener

Tags: lightning-web-components

I am trying to implement custom event handling function using salesforce lwc event handling. While dispatching event from child to parent , custom event handling function `handleCustomEvent` is not getting triggered by using this.template.addEventListener defined in constructor.

Child component html file like the following,

```
<template>
  <lightning-card title="Child Component">
    <div>
        <lightning-input name="textVal" label="Enter Text" onchange={handleChange}> 
        </lightning-input>
    </div>
 </lightning-card>
</template>
```

child .js file ,

```
export default class ChildCus extends LightningElement {

  handleChange(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    const name = event.target.value;
    const selectEvent = new CustomEvent('mycustomevent', {
        detail: name,bubbles: true
    });
   this.dispatchEvent(selectEvent);
  }
}
```

Parent component html file,

```
<template>
  <div>
    Value From Child :  {msg}
    <c-child-comp ></c-child-comp>
  </div>
</template>
```

Parent component .js file,

```
export default class ParentCus extends LightningElement {

@track msg;
constructor() {
    super();   
   
    this.template.querySelector('c-child-comp').addEventListener(
        'mycustomevent',
        this.myCustomEventHandler
      );   
}
myCustomEventHandler = (event) => {
    this.handleCustomEvent(event);
  }
handleCustomEvent(event) {
    console.log("Test Point2");
    const textVal = event.detail;
    this.msg = textVal;
  
   }
}
```

UPDATE

according to answered suggestion , I am getting `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' (at childComp:1:10)` in parent console and getting following screenshot while loading page,

[image]

In parent component js file, constructor is working without any error. But `handleCustomEvent` function is not getting triggered. Can anyone guide me to resolve this issue why its happening?

Comment: Any specific reason to not simply use `onmycustomevent` to bind a handler to that event on the child markup within the parent template?

Comment: No reason. I am beginner in salesforce. So I am learning and practicing event handling by JavaScript using addEventListener method.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [LWC and addEventListener](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/355344/lwc-and-addeventlistener)

Comment: You might also want to check the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/events_handling) which shows using binding as an "anti-pattern" when using `this.addEventListener` and `this.template.addEventListener`.

Comment: OK thank you. let me go through these.

Answer (score 2):

You always want to attach the event listener to the source, not the destination. In other words, the thing that you want to listen to is the thing you should attach the method to. Note that the event handler cannot be added before the first time your component is rendered, so:

```
// ensures that "this" is correct by way of arrow function
#myCustomEventHandler = (event) => {
  this.handleCustomEvent(event);
}
renderedCallback() {
  this.template.querySelector('c-child-comp').addEventListener(
    'mycustomevent',
    this.#myCustomEventHandler
  );
}
disconnectedCallback() {
  // Make sure we avoid memory leaks
  this.template.querySelector('c-child-comp').removeEventListener(
    'mycustomevent',
    this.#myCustomEventHandler
  );
}
```

Note that the framework does automatically avoid duplicate handlers on the same event, so it's safe to not check if the event is already being listened for.

[Demo](https://app.lwc.studio/edit/lSAJXRQJRzr2nd2KGaVS/src/child.js?p=stories).

Comment: according to answered suggestion , I am getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' (at childComp:1:10) in parent console. and getting the updated screenshot in question. Please check screnshot from edited question.

Comment: @Mr.DevEng that's a syntax error in the child component, it appears. Makes sure the code is saved correctly. Also, try testing it in a Lighting App directly in Salesforce, see if that makes a difference.