addEventListener VS ResizeObserver
I've noticed Salesforce orgs get the error ResizeObserver is not a constructor when Session Settings -> Use Lightning Web Security for Lightning web components and Aura components is not enabled.
I'm come up with an alternative solution for my LWC that does work without LWS using addEventListener. However, I'm having trouble finding out the differences between the two below solutions, and when to choose one over the other (other than that the ResizeObserver solution doesn't work without LWS). When looking at alternative solutions, it is suggested to use lightning:container and polyfill, but never just addEventListener. Will there be unforeseen consequences with using Solution A below instead of Solution B?
SOLUTION A
connectedCallback() {
     window.addEventListener('resize', this.onEventResize);
}

// arrow functions keep the this reference so I can use this.template
// https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/355344/lwc-and-addeventlistener
onEventResize = () => {
    let targetElement2 = this.template.querySelector('.svg-container');
    this.containerWidth = targetElement2.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    this.containerHeight = targetElement2.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    this.refreshD3();
}

renderedCallback() {
    const targetElement = this.template.querySelector('.svg-container');
    this.containerWidth = targetElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    this.containerHeight = targetElement.getBoundingClientRect().height;
}

SOLUTION B
renderedCallback() {
    const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
        for (let entry of entries) {
            //Handle width changes
            this.containerWidth = entry.contentRect.width;
            this.containerHeight = entry.contentRect.height;
            this.refreshD3();
        }
    );

    const targetElement = this.template.querySelector('.svg-container');
    resizeObserver.observe(targetElement);
}


Your comment made me realize that I had made a mistake. Using try-catch, as in your comment, should suffice as a workaround.

Great thank you for the insight on the slowness of window events, I didn't know that. I tried to summarize the best answer below

@sfdcfox... one small question, in your old post you mentioned Lightning Locker is being phased out. Does that mean that all SF orgs will be forced to switch to Lightning Web Service, and do you know if there is a way to know when that will happen/has happened?

I don't know what the timeline looks like, but the FAQ implies that sooner or later, LWS will replace Locker Service.

Incase anyone sees this, sfdcfox mentioned that window.addEventListener  will run slower than ResizeObserver (I think because it gets called anytime the full window resizes, not just the DOM component I care about), but that both will work. Therefore... a good solution is to attempt to use resizeObserver first...
renderedCallback() {
    try {
        const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(entries => {
            for (let entry of entries) {
                this.containerWidth = entry.contentRect.width;
                this.containerHeight = entry.contentRect.height;
                this.refreshD3();
            }
        });
        const targetElement = this.template.querySelector('.svg-container');
        resizeObserver.observe(targetElement);
    } catch {
        window.addEventListener('resize', this.onEventResize);
        this.onEventResize();
    }
}

onEventResize = () => {
    let targetElement = this.template.querySelector('.svg-container');
    this.containerWidth = targetElement.getBoundingClientRect().width;
    this.containerHeight = targetElement.getBoundingClientRect().height;
    this.refreshD3();
}

